# Waterline default query condition

Tags: model, sails.js, sti, waterline

How can I set the default where/sort condition in my SailsJS waterline model? In Rails I would use [default scope](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sails doesn't support default criteria on a per-model basis, but if you're using [blueprint routes](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/blueprint-api?q=blueprint-routes) you can set default criteria for the route by overriding in your **config/routes.js** file, for example:

```
"GET /user": {
    controller: 'user', 
    action: 'find', 
    where: {'deleted': false}, 
    sort: 'age DESC'
}
```

This will work even if you don't have a `find` action defined in your **UserController.js** file, because the blueprint is added for you by default.