# Sails Models Default values to Select?

Tags: javascript, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

On my project all the tables should have the 'status' atribute, that verify if the record is active, inactive or deleted. So I'll have to select everytime with a "...where status = active".

There's another way to do that, just once, and use at every model?

I use to work with Zend Framework, and I extend the Default Model class, is this possible with waterline?

Comment: Maybe this link can help ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080201/waterline-default-query-condition